# Convert.ToInt32(x) the same as (int)x

Tags: c#

If x is a value then are the following just syntactically different but effectively the same? Is the second a shortcut for the first?

```
Convert.ToInt32(x);
(int)x;
```

Or can one be used in some circumstances over and above the other?

Looking in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) it seems that the first is doing something different to the second.

Comment: You have the answer still on SO if you search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168704/when-to-use-a-cast-or-convert

Comment: And what's the difference between  
`int.Parse(x)`  
and  
`Convert.ToInt32(x)` ? Are they Identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(int)` is **explicit** cast where `Convert.ToInt` is method

Consider:

```
string x = "1";
int temp = 0;
temp = Convert.ToInt32(x);
temp = (int)x; //This will give compiler error
```

**Casting works for compatible types**:

```
long l = 123;
int temp2 = (int)l;

double d = 123.2d;
int temp3 = (int)d; // holds only the int part 123
```

You may see [Explicit cast - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

> if a conversion cannot be made without a risk of losing information,
>   the compiler requires that you perform an explicit conversion, which
>   is called a cast. A cast is a way of explicitly informing the compiler
>   that you intend to make the conversion and that you are aware that
>   data loss might occur.

Comment: thanks for the help `Convert.ToInt` looks pretty useful

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the other posts here, that `Convert.ToInt32` tends to round result, whilst `int`, truncates it.

Example:

```
  float x = -0.6f;
  var b = Convert.ToInt32(x);
  var r = (int)x;
```

The result of this is that `b==-1`, bur `r==0`.

This is **fundamental** difference to remember

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is a string containing a number, the first one will succeed but the second one will fail.

```
object x = "1";
Convert.ToInt32(x); // works
(int)x; // fails
```

Answer (score 1):

[Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.convert.toint32.aspx) is a method, which converts many types of objects to `int`, and `(int)` is simple casting - which may lead to exceptions

Answer (score 1):

They are different. int is a casting, ToInt32 is a conversion process. It does much more, is more tolerant of incorrect data, and pretty much always works.

Answer (score 1):

For `(int)x` , built into the CLR and requires that `x` be a numeric variable otherwise will give an exception.

`Convert.ToInt32` is designed to be a general conversion function which convert from any primitive type to a `int`.