# Decimal.Parse() vs Convert.ToDecimal()

Tags: c#

I would like to know if there is any difference between the captioned two methods?

```
string str = "14.75";
Console.WriteLine(Decimal.Parse(str));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(str));
```

Can anyone please let me know? Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todecimal(v=vs.110).aspx Convert has a lot more overloads for taking other types. TryParse is also a great one, since it won't bomb out on you if it fails.

Comment: "Using the ToDecimal(String) method is equivalent to passing value to the Decimal.Parse(String) method." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9z3s65.aspx

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Straight from MSDN documentation on Convert.ToDecimal(): The return value is the result of invoking the Decimal.Parse method onvalue.

Answer (score 4):

`Decimal.Parse` only supports parsing string values, whereas [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todecimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes other types as well, like, object, `int`, `byte`, `DateTime` etc.

Comment: Not only, not only. Another little bit about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394032/difference-between-casting-and-using-the-convert-to-method/15395832#15395832