# C# Convert String to Integer

Tags: c#, string, int, type-conversion

I have finally taken the jump from VB.net to C# so I'm still having some issues.  I am making a simple weather app that connects through a RSS feed.  I want it to return a label that determines if it is freezing outside, however; I am having issues converting the temperature string to an integer so I can determine if the temperature is less than or equal to 32 degrees.  Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace WeatherApp
{
    public partial class frmWeather : Form
    {
        string Temperature;
        public frmWeather()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void getWeather()
        {
            string query = string.Format("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=" + txtZip.Text);
            XmlDocument wData = new XmlDocument();
            wData.Load(query);
            XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(wData.NameTable);
            manager.AddNamespace("yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");
            XmlNode channel = wData.SelectSingleNode("rss").SelectSingleNode("channel");
            XmlNodeList nodes = wData.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item/yweather:forecast", manager);
            Temperature = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["temp"].Value;
        }
        private void tmrWeather_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getWeather();
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            lblTemp.Text = "" + Temperature;
            if (lblTemp.Text <= "32")
            {
                lblResult.Text = "It is freezing outside!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the "problem"?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the title.  The value is not currently an integer, it is a string.  So I cannot use comparison objects like <=

Comment: Take a look to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394032/difference-between-casting-and-using-the-convert-to-method/15395832#15395832) also. If an answer here solved your question do not forget to mark it as accepted (and eventually to upvote)!

Comment: Got to stop thinking vb and C# start thinking .Net mate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Convert.ToInt32()` method to convert your `String` into `integer`

Try This:

```
      //lblTemp.Text = "" + Temperature;  this statement is not required.
      if (Convert.ToInt32(Temperature) <= 32)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "It is freezing outside!";
        }
```

OR

you can use `int.TryParse()` method to perform the proper conversion even if the data is invalid.

Try This:

```
        int temp;
        if (int.TryParse(Temperature,out temp))
        {
             if(temp <= 32)             
             lblResult.Text = "It is freezing outside!";
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Another valid method would be

```
int temp = 0;
if (int.TryParse(lblTemp.Text, out temp))
{
     lblResult.Text = temp < 32 ? "It's freezing outside" : "Not yet freezing";
}
else
{
    // parsing error
}
```

`Convert.ToInt()` and `int.parse()` will also work, but `int.TryParse()` also guards you against exceptions in case the `lblTemp.Text` does not contain a valid integer. All of these methods, however, solve your initial problem, i.e. once you parse the string into a number, you can compare them to a fix value.

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to integer,then compare with `32` ?

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(lblTemp.Text) <= 32)
```

Or just use `Temperature` variable which is an integer

```
if(Convert.ToInt32(Temperature) <= 32)
```

This line is pointless:

```
lblTemp.Text = "" + Temperature;
```

You might want to define `Temperature` as `integer` or `double`.

Answer (score 1):

If temperature is integer, then don't use string to keep it's value. Keep temperature as integer (or double) type:

```
int Temperature;
```

And use it to compare with integer value 32:

```
private void tmrWeather_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getWeather();
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    lblTemp.Text = Temperature.ToString();

    if (Temperature <= 32)        
        lblResult.Text = "It is freezing outside!";        
}
```

Also I suggest you to use Linq to Xml for parsing:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(query);
XNamespace yweather = "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0";
Temperature = (int)xdoc.Descendants("rss")
                       .Elements("channel")
                       .Elements("item")
                       .Element(yweather + "forecast")
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you don't want to change your implementation, then simply parse temp value:

```
string temp = channel.SelectSingleNode("item")
                     .SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager)
                     .Attributes["temp"].Value;
Temperature = Int32.Parse(temp);
```

**NOTES**: I suggest you to make `int GetTemperature()` method instead of `void getWeather()` method, because method name tells that it's query method which should return some value instead of changing class state (probably you will not need `Temperature` field in this case). Also instead of hard-coded value `32` create some constant integer value with name which describes what `32` means. And finally - use [Capitalization Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) suggested by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Number("123") worked for me.