# "Specified cast is not valid" when casting array of string to array of int

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use `LINQ`'s `cast` method to cast an `array of strings` to an `array of integers` but getting the error: `Specified cast is not valid`, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
string numbers = "1,2,3,4,5";
string[] nums = numbers.Split(',');

try
{
     var ff = nums.Cast<int>().ToArray();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: See [difference between Cast and Convert](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15395832/861716).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot cast it, you must convert the values:

```
var ff = nums.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit shorter:

```
var ff = nums.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```