# What is the difference between these data type conversions?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Conversion #1:

```
int result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Conversion #2:

```
int result = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

I want to know their specific use, thanks!

Comment: You might find your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394032/difference-between-casting-and-using-the-convert-to-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two very similar operations - but with different results (in some cases).
`(int)` is a Casting [Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx). Operators are used for various things, such as Addition, Subtraction, and Bitwise operations. A conversion operator is used to implicitly(implicit), or explicitly(explicit) convert one type to another. This is an example of what the operator looks like in C# code for going from object to int:

```
public static explicit operator Int32(object obj) 
{
     return ((IConvertible)obj).ToInt32();
}
```

Using the `Convert` class does the same thing, but more explicitly, and sometimes types will have a more specific type in their class that the operator will use instead of the `Convert` class. But more often than not, they are actually calling the same thing. See [Decimal](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs,c584110dd92fc213,references) for an example of it's `ToInt32()` method.

The Convert class method (From .NET [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,fc990bd1275d43d6)):

```
public static int ToInt32(object value) {
        return value == null? 0: ((IConvertible)value).ToInt32(null);
    }
```

So in general, you can go either way. And since you are just dealing with an unboxing operation (from `object` to a struct), you won't have to worry too much if you know the type. -

However, note that if you pass a null object, it won't throw when you use `Convert.ToInt32(object obj)` because it will return 0. This can be very useful.