# System.Convert.ToDouble vs (double)

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I was surprised when exception error I was hitting using `(double)value` got fixed by changing it to `System.Convert.ToDouble(value)`.

The value was object type.

Can anyone tell me why?

Here I attach the code and error message:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return (double)value * (double)parameter;
}

Error Message: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Comment: Please include a sample of your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use a Cast or Convert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168704/when-to-use-a-cast-or-convert)

Comment: My feeling it's because of the implicit cast that you're using, but for a proper answer, can you please post a sample of your code and also tell us what the exception was that you got ?

Comment: Unboxing a boxed value that's not a double to double is explicitly not supported by C#.  It does work in VB.NET.  This restriction is a big deal, it allows for much more efficient code since there is no need to go hunting for a way to convert the value.  That mattered a great deal back in .NET 1.x, before generics.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you've boxed a value that is not a double, then try to unbox and cast in one operation, you will receive an exception:

```
int value = 42;
object val = value; // Box

double asDouble = (double)val; // This will raise an exception
```

For details, I'd recommend reading Eric Lippert's article [Representation and Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx) which discusses this in detail.

However, [Convert.ToDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55.aspx) will check the type, and handle this case, then convert the resulting integer value to a double without an exception:

```
int value = 42;
object val = value; // Box

double asDouble = Convert.ToDouble(val); // This will work fine.
```

This works by checking whether the object implements [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx), and, if so (`Int32` does), using [`IConvertible.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.todouble.aspx), which in turn uses [Int32's ToDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358709.aspx) implementation.

Comment: awesomely detailed kindly explanation